# SharePoint 2016 On-premises and Azure B2C

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know if **Azure B2C** works with **SharePoint 2016 on-premises**? This SharePoint environment in question is for external users not internal users. The objective is to move away from SQL Forms Based Authentication (FBA) to Azure.

As per this article below, in combination with Claims Provider, it is easy to configure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial

However, Microsoft's B2C FAQ says that:
"*Azure AD B2C is not meant for the SharePoint external partner-sharing scenario; see Azure AD B2B instead*". But Azure B2B is out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=applications#does-azure-ad-b2c-work-with-sharepoint-on-premises-2016-or-earlier) is not meant for the SharePoint external partner-sharing scenario. Please raise the new [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or vote for similar [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9912444-b2c-and-b2b-in-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: It's hard to convince people just by throwing a one liner. If you can briefly provide a reason behind it? I have to provide my team a technical reasoning why this is not a fit. Thanks.

Comment: B2C is not evaluating auth into SharePoint.The above [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial) you have shared is for Azure AD.                                             
 Note: AAD is not same as Azure b2c

Comment: Update: I did a POC with SharePoint 2016 On-prem with B2C with Identity Server 4 as middleware. Identity Server acts as a federation gateway where it talks to SharePoint WSFed SAML 1.1 and it authenticates with Azure B2C (external login provider)  with Open Id connect (OIDC). We are planning to implement the same.

Comment: @FlyingSquirrel how did it go? we have same setup only difference is SP 2019. It would be great help for us if you could elaborate your experience before we do POC ourselves.

Comment: Wondering how did you use IdentityServer4 as it does not support WS-Federation?

Comment: Did you use IdentityServer3 instead?

Comment: Here are the 2 articles that I followed [link](https://claires.site/2016/09/08/connecting-sharepoint-to-azure-ad-b2c)  [link](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/identityserver4-ws-federation-and-sharepoint)  Use IdentityServer4 WS Federation from Github and modify to your needs.